Qualys Agent whitelist in SE-Linux
Can anyone pls suggest
how to whitelist qualys agent in SE-Linux
i have tried in google am not getting proper command if anyone can help me to whitelist qualys agent would be great

A quick online search finds for example []this](https://docs.qualys.com/en/edr/latest/index.htm#t=edr_onboarding_for_linux%2Flinux_prerequisites-for-edr.htm) "SELinux Configuration - If SELinux is enabled for Enforcing or Permissive mode, install semodule_package, checkmodule, and restorecon." which suggests that the product is SELinux aware and capable and when the correct dependencies are installed you don't need to do anything else...
